# Characterization of limit of function by sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Claim :

> For any function $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$,
>
> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a$ iff $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=a$ for all $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset[0,\infty)$ s.t. $x_n\to\infty.$

I did $(\Rightarrow)$, and I don't know how I should show opposite.

The claim I have to show is $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists R>0$ s.t. $x>R\Rightarrow |g(x)-a|<\epsilon.$

I think I have to set specific $\{x_n\}$ and to use $$|g(x)-a|\leqq|g(x)-g(x_n)|+|g(x_n)-a|.$$

I cannot come to conclusion. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Converse" is a more appropriate word than "opposite".

Comment: But for the converse, a standard approach is proof by contradiction, which Surb gives in his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that for all $(x_n)\in [0,\infty )^{\mathbb N}$ s.t. $x_n \to +\infty $, you have that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }f(x_n)=a.\tag{E}$$

Suppose by contradiction that $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)\neq a$, that is :
$$\exists \varepsilon >0 : \forall n\in\mathbb N, \exists x_n>n:|f(x_{n})-a|\geq \varepsilon.$$
In particular, $\lim_{n\to \infty }x_n=+\infty $. Therefore, by (E),
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }f(x_n)=a.$$
In particular, there is $M\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $$|f(x)-a|<\frac{\varepsilon }{2},$$ for all $n\geq M$. This contradict $|f(x_n)-a|\geq \varepsilon $ for all $n$.